# Bayesian inference over an unknown variance

Tags: distributions, bayesian

I am observing a random variable $X \in \mathbb{R}$ which can be assumed to be normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I am interested in fitting a posterior distribution over the **unknown variance** which, according to wikipedia, can be given in closed form by an inverse-gamma. My question is, given samples $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ how can I fit this distribution, that is, calculate the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

**edit:**

I found [this pdf](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf), which gives the equations for the parameter updates, and much more relevant info.

Comment: What's your prior? Note that working out the posterior distribution for a parameter is not generally called 'fitting a distribution' ... but 'computing a posterior'. Is this for some subject?

Comment: Well, whatever is the appropriate conjugate prior, apparently the inverse gamma is used with an uniformed prior anyway.  Just semantics I suppose, this is for a research project, as a comparison to other methods.

Comment: If you want a conjugate prior, the inverse gamma is it, since that's of the same form as the likelihood. Is this for some subject?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a Thompson sampling algorithm to compare with a variant of the upper confidence bounds (UCB) algorithm for an online learning task. I suppose it's related to my phd research but more personal interest than anything. I am not really asking if the inverse-gamma was appropriate, I expected that it is, instead I am wondering how one even calculates the parameters $(\alpha,\beta)$ from data, the wikipedia page is not clear, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions

Comment: You don't calculate priors from the data. They're *priors*. You use the data to update your prior information, giving posteriors.

Comment: This classical problem is covered by standard Bayesian textbooks, eg our own [Bayesian Core](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441922865/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&tag=chrprobboo-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=1441922865).

Answer (score 2):

$\int \sigma^{-M+2}exp($$-a\over{2\sigma^2}$$)d\sigma \propto a^{-M\over2} $ is called the gamma-2 inverse step. Oftenly used when determining the distribution of the conditional posterior of $\sigma^2$.